# Why sympy gives complex roots when solving cubic equations

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am using the following code to solve a cubic equation.

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
print(solve(-0.0643820896731566*x**3 + 0.334816369385245*x**2 + 1.08104426781115*x - 2.05750838005246,x))
```

As it is a cubic equation with real coefficients, there cannot be three distinct complex roots. But it gives the following results.

```
[-3.19296319480108 - 0.e-22*I, 1.43925417946882 + 0.e-20*I, 6.95416726521169 - 0.e-20*I]
```

Could someone please tell me if something goes wrong. Is there other way to solve the equation and gives real roots?

Comment: the imaginary components of the roots are an artifact of machine precision. However, note that they are extremely small and you can safely ignore them (treat them as zero)

Comment: @Stelios I am not sure what is the usage of the artifact of machine precision. Just think that it is mathematically wrong. When and how can we safely ignore it? Or is there better way to solve the equation?

Comment: It is mathematically wrong. However, for computational purposes ,this extremely small imaginary component will (in general) have no effect. This is something that you will have to deal with when you do numerical computations on a computer. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) for more details.

Comment: @Stelios I am going to solve a large amount of cubic equations. So I wonder when the imaginary part is just an artifact of machine precision so that I can ignore it and when it is really a complex root.

Comment: This is something you will have to judge on your own, given any analytical insights you have for the roots. Note that similar doubts hold for the accuracy of the real parts of the roots. However, for most applications, these considerations are meaningless (i.e., do you really care treating a real root as complex with an imaginary component of the order 10^-22?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is a clear code level and interface level separation between
>   solvers for equations in the complex domain and the real domain. For
>   example solving =1 when  is to be solved in the complex domain,
>   returns the set of all solutions, that is {2|∈ℤ}, whereas if
>    is to be solved in the real domain then only {0} is returned.

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html

Instead of `solve()` you should be using `solveset()`

```
from sympy import var, solveset
x = var('x', real=True)
print(solveset(-0.0643820896731566*x**3 + 0.334816369385245*x**2 + 1.08104426781115*x - 2.05750838005246,x))

{-3.19296319480108, 1.43925417946882, 6.95416726521169}
```

Comment: What if it's a system of nonlinear equations? It seems like there isn't a solveset equivalent at this time.